# XAML intellisense in VS2010 doesn't work when logged in as me, but works when logged in as other users

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xaml, intellisense

On my work machine XAML intellisense does not work for me, even on a newly created WPF app.

However when another user logs in to my machine the intellisence works just fine!

I have tried `Tools->Import and Export Settings->Reset all setttings`, but to no avail.

I have looked in the registry in:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\Text Editor\XAML
```

and the Auso List Members is 1

When I look in `Tools->Options->Text Editor->XAML-> General` the Statement completion tick boxes are all grayed out.  But they are also like that on a colleague's machine and it works fine on his machine.

Any ideas what I can try next?

Comment: Does Intellisense work when you press CTRL+Space? Have you checked Tools->Options->Text Editor->All Languages and ticked the auto-complete option there? And finally, have you recently installed any VS extensions that might interfere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Sorry should have posted this some time ago)

I eventually worked out what the problem was - I had a plugin installed that I had totally forgotten about (and now can't remember which one it was)

After I removed that everything stated working again